# C++ recv socket with smaller buffer

Tags: sockets, recv

I have a server that is sending a file over socket connection to my client. The message sent is a structure containing the payload length and the payload itself.

The problem is, if the payload has 270 bytes and my buffer has only 256, when I call the receive again and append the payload of the strict received on the first receive with what I got on the second the output file get some random data between those.

For example, it I send "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" and the buffer ends on "over" it will write to the file: "the quick brown fox jumps over%&$&#57f-6$+the lazy dog"

Comment: You append by using `strcat()` ? **Don't!** read() and recv() do not give you null-terminated strings. Instead, let your program remember the sizes  of the two chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminate the string received on the first receive with NULL character '\0' before appending with the string you got on the second receive.